English Word examples for prefix ad- which is merely emphatic
The following is from Etymonline

ad- word-forming element expressing direction toward or in addition to, from Latin ad "to, toward" in space or time; "with regard to, in relation to," as a prefix, sometimes merely emphatic, from PIE root *ad- "to, near, at."


Could you please give a few word examples where prefix ad- is merely emphatic?

How did the meaning of *ad- "to, near, at" evolve to acquire the emphatic function?



Wiktionary gives examples but the most common one, acclaim, is from Latin acclāmō so it's not an English prefix there (although it seems to have been occasionally productive in English). The evolution of meaning occurred in Latin, so it's a question for Latin experts (try Latin SE).

All the examples I can find are from Latin (as adsignification, acclaim). Adspection is listed in Wiktionary but not the OED, and Wiktionary has no evidence of use. I'm not convinced this has ever been productive in English as an emphatic, except based on Latin models.

Maybe "adumbrate"? I'm not sure how much relationality is already present in umbrare...

admonish....?

Cross-posted from Linguistics.SE: https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/q/49141/10009


The following is from Etymonline

The following is from the OED
ad- prefix

1.In combinations formed in Latin and transmitted through Old or later French, as adapt v., adduce v., address v., or adapted or formed in
English, as admix v., adnumber v., with the sense ‘to, towards, near,
at’, or indicating change into, addition, adherence, increase, or
intensification.

Forming chiefly scientific adjectives and adverbs with the sense ‘position adjacent to or towards’, as adaxial adj., adoral adj.


You will note that there is nothing to indicate emphasis.
